# SVD does not converge in AML++

Tags: c++, linear-algebra

I'm using the AML++ library for matrix operations and I'm getting an SVD covergence error whenever I try to get the condition number of a matrix. I can reproduce the error even on an identity matrix with this program:

```
using namespace amlpp;

int main() {

  Real kappa = cond(eye(5,5));
  cout << kappa << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

and it gives me

```
AML++ error 116; SVD did not converge
aborting...
```

Has anyone ever seen this before? Also, responses of the form "Why are you using AML++? You should be using XXXX" will be considered thoughfully.